# Joomla - Global Configuration freeze and can't save or edit articles

Tags: joomla, permissions, joomla3.0, backend, article

Joomla version 3.3.6

Some aspects of the back end is quick and I can save, edit or create easily e.g. module manager. Going to control panel also quick.

Going to global configuration freezes the browser. I also noticed that I can't edit articles.

Everything should be standard. The only thing I played around with was groups. I've added A LOT of groups under the "Manager" group. Don't know if this could have caused the above two issues.

Please assist.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for months, I finally got it working for me. I have a bunch of custom user groups as well, so maybe this will help you too.

Turns out the error was PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.

I added this to my php.ini file
    max_input_vars = 5000